# Ternary Operator not yielding expected result

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript: I have a ternary operator being instructed to return a tip percentage of %15 if the bill amount is between $50-300, otherwise being instructed to reuturn a tip percentage of %20. On a bill amount of $275, it is still yielding %20. I have looked at many examples of functioning ternary operators and my code seems to be properly worded and yet the result comes out incorrect every time. In what way am I failing?

```
const bill_1 = 40;
const bill_2 = 275;
const bill_3 = 430;
let bill;
let tip_percentage = bill >= 50 && bill <= 300 ? 0.15 : 0.2;

bill = bill_1;
console.log(`The first table's bill came out to $${bill}. After the tip of ${tip_percentage}% (equalling: $${bill * tip_percentage}) was added, the final amount owed is: $${bill * tip_percentage + bill}`);

bill = bill_2;
console.log(`The second table's bill came out to $${bill}. After the tip of ${tip_percentage}% (equalling: $${bill * tip_percentage}) was added, the final amount owed is: $${bill * tip_percentage + bill}`);

bill = bill_3;
console.log(`The third table's bill came out to $${bill}. After the tip of ${tip_percentage}% (equalling: $${bill * tip_percentage}) was added, the final amount owed is: $${bill * tip_percentage + bill}`);
```

This is the result being given:
[image: unexpected result]

Comment: You've only calculated the value of `tip_percentage` once, before `bill` is even assigned. You'll need to recalculate that tip percentage each time `bill` changes.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with ternary operators, but because you're using a stale variable whose value is not recalculated.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt said in the comment, `tip_percentage` is not a function and must be calculated each time you change the bill amount.

Try this:

```js
const bill_1 = 40;
const bill_2 = 275;
const bill_3 = 430;

function getTip(bill) {
  var tip = (bill >= 50 && bill <= 300) ? 0.15 : 0.2;
  return tip;
}

alert(`Bill one's tip: ${getTip(bill_1)}`);
alert(`Bill two's tip: ${getTip(bill_2)}`);
alert(`Bill two's tip: ${getTip(bill_3)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

`tip_percentage` is already calculated.

If you want to make different result values depending on the variable, make them in the form of functions.

```js
const bill_1 = 40;
const bill_2 = 275;
const bill_3 = 430;
const tip_percentage = (bill) => (bill >= 50 && bill <= 300 ? 0.15 : 0.2);
const printTipResult = (bill) => {
  console.log(`The third table's bill came out to $${bill}. 
  After the tip of ${tip_percentage(bill)}% 
  (equalling: $${bill * tip_percentage(bill)}) was added, 
  the final amount owed is: $${bill * tip_percentage(bill) + bill}`);
};

printTipResult(bill_1);
printTipResult(bill_2);
printTipResult(bill_3);
```